# Example of three dimensional atoroidal Poincaré duality group with some pathology

Tags: gr.group-theory, hyperbolic-geometry, 3-manifolds, fundamental-group

I am looking for a 3-manifold which is closed, aspherical, orientable, and atoroidal. And additionally I want to see an example that does not admit a fixed-point-free action on a simplicial tree. As a group theorist myself I am more interested in the fundamental group than the manifold and a full answer to this question would include a presentation of the group.

Since Thurston's geometrization program has been realised, such a manifold must be hyperbolic and finitely covered by a surface bundle over a circle. The Seifert--Weber dodecahedral space might be such an example but I do not know whether it is or not. Such an example would lay bare the need to pass to a finite cover when establishing the surface bundle over a circle feature of closed hyperbolic 3-manifolds and its fundamental group may have other interesting pathologies.

Comment: In arxiv:2312.08913, it is mentioned that a theorem of Stallings shows that, given a closed, orientable, aspherical 3-manifold $M$, $\pi_1(M)$ has property FA iff $M$ is non-Haken. So it seems that your question amounts to finding explicit examples of non-Haken hyperbolic closed 3-manifolds.

Comment: @AGenevois yes that is right: an explicit example of a non-Haken hyprbolic closed 3-manifold would answer my question. So a natural question arises: is the Seifert--Weber dodecahedral space Haken.

Comment: Can I suggest replacing "some pathology" in the title with "Property FA"?  It's just as short and completely precise!

Comment: A small remark. The word "atoroidal" has two different meanings in 3-manifold topology: no essential *embedded* torus and no essential "immersed" torus. Examples that are atoroidal in the first sense are easier to write down (although not necessarily hyperbolic): you can use Brieskorn spheres, Seifert-fibred spaces fibring over hyperbolic triangle orbifolds.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One answer to your question comes from the paper *[The Weber-Seifert dodecahedral space is non-Haken](https://arxiv.org/abs/0909.4625)* by Burton, Rubinstein, and Tillmann.

An earlier example is (say) the $(1, 2)$-Dehn filling of the figure-eight knot.  This manifold is hyperbolic (4.22) and non-Haken (4.41).  The references are page numbers in [Thurston's lecture notes](https://archive.org/embed/ThurstonTheGeometryAndTopologyOfThreeManifolds).  We can use [SnapPy](https://snappy.computop.org/) to find presentations of the fundamental groups.

Before filling:

```
In[1]: M = Manifold("4_1")
In[2]: M.fundamental_group()
Out[2]: 
Generators:
   a,b
Relators:
   abbbaBAAB
```

After filling:

```
In[3]: M.dehn_fill((1, 2))
In[4]: M.fundamental_group()
Out[4]: 
Generators:
   a,b
Relators:
   abbbaBAAB
   abAbaBabAbaBAB
```

---

**Edit**: I remembered that [Regina](https://regina-normal.github.io/) has the Weber-Seifert manifold as one of its examples.  So, using the triangulation isomorphism signature, we can import this to SnapPy and find a presentation for its fundamental group. (We can also compute a presentation using Regina - but I prefer the notation for relations used by SnapPy).

```
In[5]: WS = Manifold("xvLvvvwMvQPPQQQQcehpjtqksntrtvoupwpsuwsvwcgacalvucahatbhapaggjgfk")
In[6]: WS.fundamental_group()
Out[6]: 
Generators:
   a,b,c,d
Relators:
   aDcbcdabdbbc
   aDabCADCbc
   abdbcdabdACBC
   aDBcdaDabbc
In[7]: WS.volume()
Out[7]: 11.1990647408
In[8]: WS.homology()
Out[8]: Z/5 + Z/5 + Z/5
```

The homology has rank three, so at least three generators are needed.  It seems to be [open](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/146529/heegaard-genus-of-the-hyperbolic-dodecahedral-space-is-it-3-or-4) (?) to compute the minimal number of generators.

Comment: Thanks Sam this is a very clear answer!!

Comment: BTW, improvements in code and hardware allowed Ben Burton to verify that the Weber-Seifert space is non-Haken in 2016 running the code in 75 minutes. https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.11686 (see the end of Section 1).